# Why do I have to use an import in my subclass, when it's already in the superclass?

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have two questions.

I have an Apple class that extends an abstract Fruit class see code below ↓

First question: Why do I have to use the `import java.awt.Color;` in my apple class, since it's already in my Fruit class? I get an error: cannot find symbol

Second question: in my apple constructor I have  `String result = seasonal ? "yes" : "no";` (I want boolean to print "Yes" or "No") is that right would it be better in the Fruit boolean method or public static void main? If yes how do I do that?

Apple.java

```
import food.Fruit;
import java.awt.Color;

class Apple extends Fruit {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Fruit apple = new Apple(Color.RED, true);
    apple.prepare();
    System.out.println("Color: " + apple.getColor());
  }

  public Apple(Color color, boolean seasonal) {
    super(color, seasonal);
    String result = seasonal ? "yes" : "no";
    System.out.println("Seasonal: " + result);
  }

  @Override
  public void prepare() {
    System.out.println("Cut the Apple");
  }
}
```

Fruit.java

```
package food;

import java.awt.Color;

public abstract class Fruit {
  private Color color;
  private boolean seasonal;

  public Fruit(Color color, boolean seasonal) {
    this.color = color;
    this.seasonal = seasonal;
  }

  public abstract void prepare();

  public Color getColor() {
    return color;
  }

  public boolean isSeasonal() {
    return seasonal;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't ask more than one question per post. Also note that the title is discouraged because it does not summarize the body.

Comment: @FrancescoMenzani OK I did not realize it was only one question per post, in future I will stick to rules :)

Comment: There are two questions indeed.

Comment: Yes indeed, does that mean you will take back your down vote :) ?

Comment: I've downvoted this question because it contains two problems. Votes are for the post, not the poster. Do not take them personally. I'm glad you will stick to the rules because you will get many upvotes on the _next_ post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **First question: Why do I have to use the import java.awt.Color; in my apple class, since it's already in my Fruit class?**

Because it's not in your Fruit class. It's in the *compilation unit* -- the source file -- that includes your Fruit class. The import applies to all the code within the one source file that contains it.

Imports are not inherited, because source files don't have inheritance.

From the Java language specification, [section 7.5: Import declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5):

> *An import declaration makes types or members available 
>   by their simple names only within the compilation unit 
>   that actually contains the import declaration.*

On to question 2 ...

> **Second question: in my apple constructor I have  String result = seasonal ? "yes" : "no"; (I want boolean to print "Yes" or "No") is that right would it be better in the Fruit boolean method or public static void main? If yes how do I do that?**

You have these two lines:

```
String result = seasonal ? "yes" : "no";
System.out.println("Seasonal: " + result);
```

The second line would be best placed in *neither* `Fruit.isSeasonal()` or the `Apple()` constructor. In these functions, the print would be a *side-effect* that might not be desired by some callers.

Including this code in `Apple.main()` is reasonable.

Another possibility is to define a `toString()` or similar method to build a description, and then print the description wherever you like.

```
public abstract class Fruit  
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append( "Color: " + color.toString() );

        String result = seasonal ? "yes" : "no";
        builder.append("\nSeasonal: " + result);

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

This allows you to extend the description in subclasses:

```
 class Apple extends Fruit {
    private AppleVariety appleVariety;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String description = super.toString();
        description += "\nApple variety: " + appleVariety;
        return description;
    }
 }
```

Comment: this is brilliant thanks, especially considering I broke the rules and asked two questions. I wrote the above code into my files and I am getting an error below, I wonder would apple.getColor() in the fruit class be better as fruit.getColor(), then I would have to create a fruit var? `Fruit.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    builder.append( "Color: " + apple.getColor());
                                ^`

Comment: Good catch, `apple.getColor()` was a copy-and-paste error. Fixed above. You don't need `fruit.getColor()` because `toString()` is an instance method with access to the instance's members. You could use any of the following: `color`, `this.color`, `getColor()` or `this.getColor()`.

Comment: Yes Fruit class now complies, however I had an error with `private AppleVariety appleVariety;` so I changed it too `private String appleVariety = "Red Delicious";` now when I `System.out.println(apple);` I get `Color: java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
Seasonal: Yes
Apple variety: Red Delicious`

Comment: That works too. 

Alternatively, you could write a class or enum called AppleVariety. An enum would be reasonable if the enum class knew all the possible AppleVariety instances at compile time. A class `AppleVariety` would allow varieties that you don't know about yet.

Regardless, you would probably want to initialize the variety field via an Apple constructor.

Answer (score 4):

First question:
Imports do not get inherited. Just because you extend a class, that imports something does not import that class's imports. Long story short: you need to import everything you need in a .java file.

Second question:
Whenever possible and **sensible**, move code from child-classes to parent-classes. This reduces code repetition.

Comment: And you usually don't want a constructor or `boolean isX()` method to print anything. Whenever possible, you want to avoid *side-effects* in function definitions. So, given those two options, the `print()` would be better in `Apple.main()` than in the Apple constructor or `Fruit.isSeasonal()`. Another option would be to provide a `toString()` method that constructs an appropriate description.